# PoissonDistribution- Demand problems

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I am still not too familiar with Poisson Distribution and recently I have come across a question like the following

A grocery store purchases one item for $X$ dollars and sells it for $Y$ dollars.
If the item is unsold, they can not refund it. The demand for the item varies according to a $Poisson(\lambda)$ distribution. The question is what is the number of items that the store should order from the supplier....

I can't seem to wrap my head around this type of question as I cant find a way to apply the Poisson distribution.

Can anyone elaborate on this to me?

Comment: Are you having a *specific* question, then post it *exactly*  ?

Comment: @true blue anil Sorry, I have seen a couple of similar questions like this. So I think it would be a good idea to post the form and ask for a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Consider the following questions - you might not want to try to find closed forms:

- If the shop buys $n$ items for $X$ each, how much does it spend?
- What is the probability that shop the sells $N$ items (with $0 \le N \lt n$)? Use the Poisson distribution here
- What is the shop's revenue if it sells $N$ items (with $0 \le N \lt n)$?
- What is the probability that shop the sells at least $n$ items? Use the Poisson distribution here and you might want to leave this as a sum
- What is the shop's revenue if it sells $n$ items?
- What is the shop's expected gross revenue if it cannot sell more than $n$ items?
- What is the shop's expected net profit if it orders $n$ items?
- What would the previous answers be if you replaced $n$ by $n+1$?
- What is the change in net profit if you replaced $n$ by $n+1$?
- For which $n$ does the change in net profit first become negative?

Comment: How should I calculate the gross revenue and net profit I'm a bit confused

Comment: also How would I calculate the cumulative Poisson Distribution if n is unknown or very large?

Comment: Expected gross revenue is the sum of the product of the probability of particular sales and the value of those sales. Expected net profit is expected gross revenue minus the cost of purchasing the stock.  You can either leave the cumulative Poisson as a sum, or use the incomplete or regularised Gamma function, or approximate using the normal distribution.

Comment: if the Poisson Distribution is $\lambda$, wouldnt it  be the number of items the store should purchase?

Comment: I would expect the answer to also depend on $X$ and $Y$